# How to debug status ORA-28500 ("relation `X` does not exist") in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, system

```
select "gt.shiftkerja","i.jenis","i.konsinyasi","gp.group" from "tbl_ikhd gt"@PG  
join "tbl_ikdt dt"@PG on "gt.notransaksi"="dt.notransaksi"
join "tbl_item i"@PG on "dt.kodeitem"="i.kodeitem"
LEFT JOIN "group_posting gp"@PG on "gp.kode_group"="i.jenis"and "gp.konsinyasi"="i.konsinyasi"
where to_char("gt.tanggal", 'YYYY-MM-DD')='2017-09-08' group by "gt.shiftkerja","i.jenis","i.konsinyasi","gp.group" order by "gt.shiftkerja","gp.group";
```

this my error

> status: ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system
>   returned this message: ERROR: relation "group_posting gp" does not
>   exist; No query has been executed with that handle {42P01,NativeErr =
>   1} ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from PG

Comment: Pro-tip: please use useful titles here. "Please help me" is not useful, and "getting error" is not sufficiently detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all the quotation marks from your query. Some of these are especially bad, e.g.

```
FROM "tbl_ikhd gt"
```

What that is attempting to say is find a table with EXACTLY that name (including the space), that should read like this:

```
FROM tbl_ikhd gt
```

Now the table name is `tbl_ikhd` and the alias for that table is `gt`.

So after removing all quotations and it should look like this:

```
SELECT
      gt.shiftkerja
    , i.jenis
    , i.konsinyasi
    , gp.group
FROM tbl_ikhd gt
JOIN tbl_ikdt dt ON gt.notransaksi = dt.notransaksi
JOIN tbl_item i ON dt.kodeitem = i.kodeitem
LEFT JOIN group_posting gp ON gp.kode_group = i.jenis AND gp.konsinyasi = i.konsinyasi
WHERE to_char(gt.tanggal, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2017-09-08'
GROUP BY
      gt.shiftkerja
    , i.jenis
    , i.konsinyasi
    , gp.group
ORDER BY
      gt.shiftkerja
    , gp.group;
```

**BUT** please change the way you filter for the date. Currently you are changing every row of data by the function to_char. This removes access to an index on the date column. A better way is to just alter the way you filter the data so the data remains unaffected by functions, like this:

```
WHERE gt.tanggal >= to_date('2017-09-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND gt.tanggal < to_date('2017-09-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: ok, but the dblink is gone ,,am so confuse to write this sql stetment with dblink,,wkwkwk,,

Comment: Sorry but I  don't understand your comment